# Programming: Extracting out strings (excluding white spaces) using regex expressions

Tags: r, regex

So what I'm trying to do over here is to extract out the words (excluding white spaces) before the word 'Charlie'.

```
a = 'Charlie is at the pet shop.'
b = '   Charlie is at the pet shop.'
c = 'Jane saw Charlie at the pet shop.'
```

What I've attempted so far:

```
> gsub('(.*?)((\\s)*Charlie).*','\\1',a)
[1] ""
> gsub('(.*?)((\\s)*Charlie).*','\\1',b)
[1] "   "
> gsub('(.*?)((\\s)*Charlie).*','\\1',c)
[1] "Jane saw "
```

What I want to achieve:

```
[1] ""
[1] ""
[1] "Jane saw "
```

May I know why doesn't the code above works? Also, how should I modify the regex pattern so I can achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply,

```
sub('Charlie.*', '', x)
 #[1] ""          "   "       "Jane saw "
```

Or

```
sub('Charlie.*', '', trimws(x))
#[1] ""          ""          "Jane saw "
```

Comment: Didn't know there's a trimws() function on R! Thank you so much for your help! :)

Comment: Yes, if the point is to remove all the text starting with the first `Charlie` to the end of the string, this will work. But I would use `sub` rather than `gsub` since there is only 1 replacement expected.

Answer (score 3):

It does not look pretty with `sub`, but it can be done like this:

```
> sub(".*?(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)*)\\s+Charlie.*|.+", "\\1", x)
[1] ""         ""         "Jane saw"
```

**Details**:

- `.*?` - any chars, as few as possible
- `(\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)*)` - Group 1 (`\\1`):

  - `\\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace chars
  - `(?:\\s+\\S+)*` - zero or more sequences of 1+ whitespaces followed with 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `\\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `Charlie`  - a substring
- `.*` - any 0+ chars up to the string end
- `|` - or
- `.+` - any 1+ chars (to zero the string)

With *stringr* `str_extract`, it will look better:

```
> library(stringr)
> res <- str_extract(x, "\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)*(?=\\s+Charlie\\b)")
> res
[1] NA         NA         "Jane saw"
```

The `"\\S+(?:\\s+\\S+)*(?=\\s+Charlie\\b)"` matches 1+ non-whitespaces, then 0+ sequences of 1+ whitespaces and 1+ non-whitespaces *immediately followed* with 1+ whitespaces and then `Charlie` as a whole word.

**EDIT**:

Just adding up on the [@Sotos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44842950/3832970): you may use `sub` instead of `gsub` since only one replacement is expected, and you may "trim" the spaces before `Charlie` with `\s*`:

```
> sub('\\s*Charlie.*', '', x)
[1] ""         ""         "Jane saw"
```

Here,

- `\\s*` - finds the first set of 0+ whitespace chars followed by...
- `Charlie` - substring `Charlie` followed by
- `.*` - any 0+ chars up to the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation!! It certainly helped me in understanding your codes! :)

Comment: Great options as always!

Comment: Just FYI: judging by the question, there is no need to for a word boundary in the second solution, but I often insert it automatically when the question mentions *words*. If you need to match when the text contains `Charlies`, please remove that `\b`.